# Retrieve MOID from vmware soap api for ESX Host

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I am not able to find the API to retrieve the MOID or Managed Refernce Object ID of a given Managed Object, from the VMWare SOAP API. I am using the vmware65 library. I was able to find it for vCenter but could not for ESX Host.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you trying to find the moref of a particular host? What information do you have on the host - e.g. do you have its name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vSphere API, then you can connect to the vCenter Server and use the following to get mobid of ESX servers by:

```
 Get-VMHost -name hostname | get-view | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MoRef
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need it through the SOAP API. I am using Java as the client for the SOAP API